# change width of a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, html, width

I am trying to change my "inner" div's width dynamically on the click that the images are changed (which works) with a similar script. I cannot get the script to work, any help fixing it, or changing it would be appreciated. I am a noob in javascript so please be nice ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function setBase(baseval) {
    var images = document.getElementById("mylist").getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = baseval + ((i<9)?0+i:i) + ".jpg"; 
     }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function setStyle(baseval) {
    var style = document.getElementById("inner").getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    style[i].style = baseval + "px"; 
     }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="mylist" style="  height: 481px; width: 700px; overflow-x: auto;  ">
<div id="inner" style="width: 7300px ">

        <img src="carousel_img/1/1.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/2.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/3.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/4.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/5.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/6.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/7.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/8.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/9.jpg" height="450" />
    <img src="carousel_img/1/10.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/0.jpg" height="450" />
        <img src="carousel_img/1/11.jpg" height="450" />

</div>
</div>
<p>
<a href="#" onclick="setBase('carousel_img/1/'); setStyle('7300'); return false;">Set A</a>
<a href="#" onclick="setBase('carousel_img/3/'); setStyle('6300'); return false;">Set B</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it the hard way. Get rid of the **fixed width** of the `inner` div (which is the cause of all that unnecessary JavaScript problems) and just solve it with help of a good shot of CSS. Even more, the inner div is technically superfluous. Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2172338</title>
        <style>
            #carousel {
                width: 150px;
                height: 100px;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="carousel">
            <img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" width="250" height="61">
            <img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" width="250" height="61">
            <img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" width="250" height="61">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This function doesn't look right:

If you're trying to set the width of the images, then this:

```
function setStyle(baseval) {
    var style = document.getElementById("inner").getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        style[i].style = baseval + "px"; 
    }
}
```

should look like this:

```
function setStyle(baseval) {
    var images = document.getElementById("inner").getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].style.width = baseval + "px"; 
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you're trying to set the width of the div itself, then it should look like this:

```
function setStyle(baseval) {
    var div = document.getElementById("inner");
    div.style.width = baseval + "px"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since "inner" is already a div, there is no need to call getElementsByTagName. So try this:

```
var innerDiv = document.getElementById("inner");
innerDiv.style.width = baseval + "px";
```

(Since 'style' is a keyword, I used a different variable name)

Answer (score 0):

substitute

```
style[i].style = baseval + "px";
```

with

```
 style[i].style.width = baseval + "px";
```

and give it a try