# Javascript object css manipulation

Tags: javascript, css, object

just a basic question

I have an object and I'm trying to get the css property out of it. So what I want is like this

```
var width = e.style.width;
```

I'm like 90% sure that width would become a string, but then again I'm not really sure. 
I can set the the objects with

```
e.style.width = 200;
```

so it places an int or float or w/e value I want but not sure how to get the css style out.

Thanks

Comment: parseFloat do the job, but you will have troubles with percentages, the answer from @koder will be more usefull for a better code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
parseFloat(e.style.width);
```

This will strip out the "px" out of the value and give you the actual value in pixels.

Comment: And will also do "fun stuff" for a value of `100%`, should such be encountered ..

Answer (score 3):

you should use as following

```
e.style.width = '80.2%';
e.style.width = '80.2em';
```

Please see following links [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118172/setting-div-width-and-height-in-javascript) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172338/change-width-of-a-div-dynamically)

and if you try get width using javascript then you could use as following code

```
parseFloat(e.style.width);
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting object width you can use clientWidth or offsetWidth as (both will return you an integer):

```
var width = e.clientWidth;
```

or

```
var width = e.offsetWidth;
```

and to set object width you can use the following code:

```
e.style.width = "200px";
```